# WIX Feature Tree with Checkbox selection

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix-extension

I am in need to add a Features tree with checkbox selection to my msi. Can any one point me to some sample as how to achieve this please?

I already have one Feature element (ProductMain) that installs all the mandatory components. I have tried using the built-in CustomizeDlg and FeaturesDlg but not sure how to change the Selection tree to use Checkboxes

I am using WIXUI_Common set of dialogs.

I would appreciate any suggestion/guidance in this regard.

Sincere thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're limited to the UI supported by Windows Installer (which is quite limited). I don't think you can customize the [SelectionTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371604.aspx) control to display checkboxes. Alternatively, you can emulate the desired behavior by placing a number of checkboxes on a dialog and implement a certain logic to set feature levels.

Comment: This is true. With Windows Installer a solution is to use a custom dialog with checkboxes and a custom action which changes feature states based on the checkbox properties. Another solution is external UI for the MSI. If you want a commercial tool, Advanced Installer supports this.

Comment: Thanks Yan and Cosmin for your reply. I think for now I will continue with the built-in dialog.

Comment: If you are doing custom feature logic this is a good article to checkout: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/